# How can I hide folder name from URL

Tags: wordpress, web, url, multilingual, polylang

My website address is https://www.promotech.eu/en/. I am running a site that is designed to be multilingual, using Polylang as the means to achieve this. I have a question: Is there a way to hide the "/en/" extension in the URL so that the address remains the same—https://www.promotech.eu/—across all languages? This "/en/" directory was not created through Polylang but was set up long ago during the initial WordPress installation.

JK

I think I will be able to change it via htaccess file but don't know how.

Comment: Having the language in the URL is recommended for SEO.  Search engines won't be able to index your site if you don't differentiate the URL for each language.